# MySql query using two tables with Inner join (i think)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get this query to work, I just want to display record where Physio Reference (from table 1) equals `SESS_MEMBER_ID` (from a members table in MySQL but is from a session created from login).

I'm not sure exactly how to do this as I'm still grasping the concept of php. I'm not sure if you have to put some code at the end to tell it that the field is from the table `members`.

my aim is to only display records from the IA tables PhysioReference field, where that fields equals the SESS_MEMBER_ID kept in the session from the members table.

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=SESS_MEMBER_ID";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**Members** - table name

> member_id,    firstname,  lastname,   login,  passwd,

**IA** - table name

> Reference,  Forename,   Surname,    DOB,    PhysioReference,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error (or unexpected results) you are getting?

Comment: @fluffeh for example; user logged in has an ID of 100351 (which is confirmed by an echo for testing purposes, echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']). so I just want where the 'SESS_MEMBER_ID' of the users session (from the login) equals a record in the IA table's PhysioReference (e.g. 'SESS_MEMBER_ID' = 100351 and PhysioReference from IA = 100351, then display that result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you might have missed the dollar sign in the query:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=$SESS_MEMBER_ID";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

As the query is inside double quotes, you can use the variable inside the query without issue or needing to concatenate. If however your member ID is a string (alphanumeric) you will need some single quotes inside the statement as follows:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id='$SESS_MEMBER_ID'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

On that note, if you haven't already made a variable with it, you are referencing the session incorrectly. You might want to try something along these lines:

Edit (Based on Comment):

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: I believe you was right on the last option, as im pretty new to this and problem haven't referenced the session correctly. I have tried the all 3 options but doesn't display, do I have to define the variable first?

Comment: Yes you do mate. Yu should reference the session as you assign it. Whatever you assing/save the session variable as, is how you need to reference it in your SQL statement. You can check this easily enough through an `echo $sql;` just before you execute it to make sure the variable is being passed properly.

Comment: echo returns **SELECT * FROM IA tb1, members tb2 WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id AND tb2.member_id=**

Comment: Looks like your session isn't being assigned/passed properly. You shold verify in your code that it is being assigned properly (You can do this by echo'ing it out just after you save it) and the make sure that you are using the EXACT same session variable in your query to make sure creates the SQL as you expect it to be made.

Comment: how would I assign the $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] to a variable to use in the query?... when I echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];... it returns the correct ID

Comment: @user3301611 I edited the SQL in the last part of my answer which should hopefully work for you as it is written.

Comment: We do what we can to help mate. That's the whole point of SO. The only thing that would complete this lovely circle is, if one day you helped answer another question posed when you feel confident in doing so.

Comment: I do look now and again for simple questions to answer but none as of yet lol... but seriously many thanks

Comment: There isn't a rush. When this stuff becomes second nature to you, the answers will come quick and fast. In the meantime, best of luck with the coding - and if you get stuck again, feel free to keep asking questions good sir!

Answer (score 0):

Defined variables don't get parsed inside a string.

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=" . SESS_MEMBER_ID;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Or, if it is a string:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id='" . SESS_MEMBER_ID . "'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Or, maybe it is not a defined variable, but a session variable?

```
// At the start of your code.

session_start();

// ... 

$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id=" . $_SESSION["MEMBER_ID"];
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Or, if the `MEMBER_ID` is a string:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
      FROM IA tb1, members tb2 
      WHERE tb1.PhysioReference=tb2.member_id
      AND tb2.member_id='{$_SESSION["MEMBER_ID"]}';
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

(Or if you called it `SESS_MEMBER_ID`, try `$_SESSION["SESS_MEMBER_ID"]`.)

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work, can I give you any more information to help? I just want to display record where PhysioReference from the IA table equals the SESS_MEMBER_ID.

Comment: You might want to replace `SESS_MEMBER_ID` -if you haven't done a `define`- with `$_SESSION["MEMBER_ID"]` or whatever (if it should be in the session, do `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check; Also, don't forget `session_start();`).

Comment: I think you are right I just don't know how to do that part in my code, any chance you could put it in your answer please?